Is this part of the grounding electrode network and does it need to be hooked into my new service?
I found this on the outside of my house.  As a note, the house was build in the 50s and the electric probably hasn't changed much since that time - the grounding all around is pretty bad.  I'm doing a heavy up and bringing up to 2023 NEC (Dayton, OH), including a new service to a new meter/main.
I recently asked a question about the grounding/bonding, and this is really an addendum to that:  A bare copper cable (looks to be 6AWG, could be 4) departs from the meter box (which is not the bonding point or disconnect point, so I'm a little confused - there's only an SEU cable running from it to my main panel, which IS the bonding point for ground) and goes into this block on the side of my house.  ChatGPT suggested it might be a grounding block for cable or satellite - I do have my internet coming in somewhat near here, but not very near.
Additionally, as far as I can tell (unless Neutral and this GND are bonded inside the meter, which I can't see) this cable would not have been in contact with any of the grounding/bonding that was present inside the building, so... could it even have been doing anything?
The cable goes from the meter to this box, then (apparently un-spliced, just passing through this block) continues to a ground rod (that I plan on re-using as 1 of the 2 rods for my heavy-up), where it ends as far as I can tell.
What is this block?  Do I need to hook it into the grounding network when I redo it?



Could be an add on grounding block for outside stuff(TV antenna) and to ground the meter box.  That cover looks newer than the 50s.

It is definitely a grounding block. The symbol on the cover is for "Ground".  As for what the wires are attached to, we cannot tell.

It is called an Intersystem Bonding Termination Device. Its purpose is to provide a point for Communication Systems to be bonded. If installed compliant with NEC 250.94 the wire you see should connect your service to the grounding electrodes. The blocks I have used have one open sided connection to allow the grounding electrode conductor to pass through uncut.
Definitely not 1950s. Somebody upgraded the Service Bonding. Often 1950s services were bonding by steel water pipe entering the building. Often during plumbing repair or retrofit the pipe is replaced with plastic and new ground rod(s) need to be installed. Steel pipe entering or in the building still needs to be bonded, but is considered inadequate to serve as sole electrode.

I found the exact same model (or one that looked VERY similar) at Lowes, so you've nailed it.  I guess I'll hook it up to the tail end of the grounding electrode conductor, and I can try to carry a ground wire from my cable service out to here to bring it up to spec.
